# Javafx Node position in Scrollpane

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

I want to know, if a node is visible at the current view position of a scrollpane and also how much.

Does anyone know how to read the position values of a node according to this issue?
I tried it already with getBoundsInParent.getMaxX(), but this seems not to be the right way, because the parent of the node is not directly the scrollpane.

Answer (score 1):

To get the visible height of the scrollpane use

```
scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
```

Comment: You only get the height of the scrollpane viewport, not its position in the displayed content.